# converting special characters after reading a site's meta tags

Tags: php

I'm pulling the Facebook meta tags from an external site with this code, which works:

```
$site = file_get_contents($link);
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($site);
$meta_title = null;
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:title'){ 
        $meta_title = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
 }
echo 'og:title: '.$meta_title;
```

My problem is that if the og:title contains something with an apostrophe, for example, it outputs a bunch of funky characters. For example:

> Thatâ€™s the Spot

Instead of:

> That's the Spot

How do I make it output correctly?

Comment: Dont use @, check for errors

Comment: @Phantom I removed the @ and turned on error reporting - nothing. This is the URL I'm working with: http://www.vnews.com/home/12496336-95/thats-the-spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the third part website collation, it was on utf-8 or latin.

Then you should convert to your website collation. What are you using? utf8 or latin?

If you are using utf8 and third part latin, you should use

```
utf8_encode($actualVar)
```

If you are using latin and the third part utf8, you should use

```
utf8_decode($actualVar)
```

I suppose there are 2 different collations ruling it. If Are The Two UTF8 Convert your php header to utf8 too:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If you are trying to use Latin (iso-8859-1) Use

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

By the wall should work any way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was including the UTF-8 encoding meta tag at the top of the PHP file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```